# Program to set icon of files according to filename

Tags: gratis, windows-7, icon, filenames

I'm looking for a program that allows me to set the icon of lots of documents to the initials of their filename.

For example, if a `.doc` file is called `Sample Document`, then the icon of the file should be `SD`.

Features:

- free
- automatic after clicking 'go' (or similar ;)
- run on Windows 7 64-bit

This will be useful for finding documents on my desktop (I have a lot :). The icon will make it easier to find the file I want rather than looking at each filename separately.

An example of this is is the Gmail app for IOS - the sender's initials are in the 'logo':

[image]

(look at the left image - Hannah Cho. Got the image from [here](http://www.cultofmac.com/229155/gmail-for-desktop-ios-and-android-gets-a-whole-new-inbox/))

Comment: You are talking about the files icons in Windows Explorer, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, I am